# About cron every day

Tags: magento2, cron

1. In Magento 2.2
2. php 7.1

Everyday this cron email comes, but I don;t know how to fix it. Please help. Thank you!!!

> 1. setup-cron: Please check var/log/update.log for execution summary.
>      [2017-11-01 05:02:07] setup-cron.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User XXXX already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections [] []
>      [2017-11-01 13:02:37] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
>      [2017-11-01 13:02:37] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
>      [2017-11-01 13:02:37] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
>      [2017-11-01 16:09:35] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
>      [2017-11-01 16:09:35] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
>      [2017-11-01 16:09:35] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
>      [2017-11-01 16:31:48] update-cron.WARNING: Update is already in progress. [] []
>      [2017-11-01 08:38:22] setup-cron.ERROR: ".update_in_progress.flag" cannot be created. [] []
>      [2017-11-01 09:18:23] setup-cron.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User XXXX already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections [] []
>      [2017-11-01 09:19:23] setup-cron.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User XXXX already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections [] []
>      [2017-11-01 09:20:15] setup-cron.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User XXXX already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections [] []
> 2. [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]
>      SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User XXXX  already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
>      [PDOException]
>      SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User XXXX already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
>      cron:run [--group GROUP] [--bootstrap BOOTSTRAP]

Comment: I am also having issues with cron jobs and getting too many connections error and server memory gets full. I scheduled server cronjobs on every 15 minutes and it's ok.